# Почему не меняется файл php.ini в laradock?

Tags: php, laradock

Все привет.
Установил docker, docker-compose и laradock.
Прописал настройки в nginx и в /etc/hosts.
Сайт открываетя и полет нормальный.
Только заметил, что не работает показ ошибок.
Потом узнал, что нужно в php.ini прописать display_errors On.

У меня в .env версия php 7.2
В laradock в файле /home/serii/Web/laradock/php-fpm/php7.2.ini поменял настройку display_errors на On.

Потом выполнил `sudo docker-compose down`
И rebuild для php-fpm `sudo docker-compose build worker php-fpm`

Потом `sudo service  apache2 stop && sudo docker-compose up -d nginx php-fpm mysql workspace`

В workspace php.ini находится в /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini

И там display_errors Off.

Только почему-то php.ini в phpinfo() находится по другому пути, но в workspace такой путь не существует.

[image: php.ini]

Уже пол дня роюсь в сети и не могу найти внятного ответа.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Потому что CLI и PHP-FPM это разные среды исполнения кода, и у каждого свои php.ini настройки. Зачем вы смотрите на CLI настройки когда используете PHP-FPM? Надеюсь что ваш [баг-репорт](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/3093) поможет вам больше, хотя там уже есть закрытые [баги](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/832) по этому поводу.

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили. 
Я передумал использовать laradock, потому что он жрет много рессурсов. 
Я установил lamp, и теперь ошибки отображаются.

Answer (score 0):

Установил lamp вместо laradock и ошибки отображаются.